# Set a hover class on a element if a parent element does not have class xy

Tags: html, css

with

```
".edtr_element:not(.edtr_active_container):hover {..."
```

I can make a style if a element class does not have the (class).

Now I have the situation, that I have to check if a element which is with the mouse hover, is in a div which does not have a class xy.

Example

```
<div id="mydiv1" class="divclass1">
  <div id="mydiv2" class="divclass2"></div>
</div>
```

How can I set a CSS :hover class if I am over the div2 but in div 1 is not the class "divclass1"?

Is it possible only by CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```css
div:not(.divclass1) > div:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv1" class="divclass1">
  <div id="mydiv2" class="divclass2">
    Test
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mydiv3" class="divclass2">
  <div id="mydiv4" class="divclass2">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML chunk you provided is not correct, because it can't contain different tags with the same ID

Answer (score 1):

Your selector would probably look like this:
`*:not(.divclass1) > .divclass2:hover {...}`

`*:not(.divclass1)` selects every element  that is not "divclass1" `> .divclass2` selects every direct child that has "divclass2" and `:hover` obviously defines the hover styles for this element.

Hope this helps